# Helicity Representation of Massive Spinor

Tags: fermions, spinors, helicity

For massless [spinors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spinor) case we can decompose momentum into Weyl sub-parts as

$$p = \lambda_{a}\tilde \lambda_{\dot a}.$$

But for the case of massive fermions can I do something like this? Decompose them into Weyl subparts with some additional terms? If so, how?

Why do I need it? I am performing a twistor transform for the equation of the process $q\bar q \to gg$ so I have to write the amplitude and the 4d delta function of the momentum and then Fourier transform the $\lambda$ and $\tilde \lambda$ separately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Ref](http://arxiv.org/abs/0908.0738v2.pdf) - Formulae 2-1 and 2-19

Suppose a given light-like momentum $q$.

Then, for each momentum $k$, such as $k.q \neq 0$, there exist a light-like  momentum $k^l$, such as :

$$k = k^l + \frac{k^2}{2 k.q}q$$

So you can write :

$$k_{\alpha \dot\alpha } = k^l_\alpha ~k^l_{\dot\alpha} + \frac{k^2}{2 k.q} q_\alpha ~q_{\dot\alpha}$$

Comment: shouldnt there be $2 k^l .q$ in the denominator

Comment: $k.q = k^l.q$, because $q^2=0$

Comment: yeah!! sorry my bad :)

Comment: okay one more quick question how do i simplify $<pq>$ where p is for a massive fermion and q is for massless gluon. In weyl representation $<pq> = p_a q^a $ in weyl representation. The notation you gave me in this for massive particles $k_{a\dot a}$ cannot be decomposed into  $k_a$ and $k_{\dot a}$ so how do i express $<pq>$

Comment: Frankly, the whole formalism seems not so easy, and I am not a specialist of it.I can only give you the following [reference](http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-ph/0703021) - Chapter 2.2 (2.2 Spinors and polarisation vectors) - page 4 . But there is some work to do to completely understand the formalism.